# VLookup multiple values

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, lookup

I have a table of Dates and Days in a specific time range called `Data`
I also have a sheet of a specific employee called "Jackson" and a sheet for employees to input their free time in so I can generate `Jackson` sheet.

I tried `VLookup` so if Jackson input `Monday`" as his free time, the `Jackson` sheet will print out a template of all Mondays in the given time range. I want it also to print out the dates based on the table of date/days.

Here is a picture of what I would like:
[image: Click here to view photo]

Stack Overflow has saved me SO MANY MANY MANY times, thank you for your helps!

Comment: You would need to share an example of your data, and the formula(e) that you're using so far.  If you need multiple values, you generally would use multiple formulas, one in each cell that you're retrieving a value.  Thus, I'm not sure why VBA would be necessary and this isn't really a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (and may be better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).)  There are numerous examples of how to use `VLookup` on this site and others.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "&" between the two lookup criterion and table arrays. Be sure to make the formula an array with ctrl shift enter